# Tilt compensation for yaw calculation from magnetometer and accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer, imu, compensation, magnetometer

I am working on a project where I have to calculate the roll, pitch, and yaw angles using an accelerometer and a magnetometer.

I calculate the pitch and roll angles using the accelerometer and I am trying to calculate the yaw using tha magnetometer with the following equation:

```
 xM2 = xM * cos(pitch) + zM * sin(pitch);
 yM2 = xM * sin(roll) * sin(pitch) + yM * cos(roll) - zM * sin(roll) * cos(pitch);
 compHeading = (atan2(yM2, xM2) * 180 / Pi);
```

I am trying to implement tilt compensation, so that no matter the position of the x and y axis, the yaw angle can be calculated.

I can assure the roll and pitch angles from the accelerometer are right and the magnetometer compensation is correct. The pitch and roll are [-180 180].

The problem I am facing, is that I think I am using the equation wrong, as the accelerometer and magnetometer axes are not exactly the same.

The following image show both axes:

[image]

Can anyone confirm the equation is used correctly?

Comment: **1)** Which set of axes (accelerometer or magnetometer) are the axes to which `pitch` , `yaw`, and `roll` are defined ?  **2)** Can you add a diagram ? **3)** "*i think i am using the equation wrong*". What makes you think so ? If the hardware is already set up, can you simply test the results at known positions ?

Comment: Since `YA = -YM` and `ZA = -ZM` and `XA = XM`, simplest scheme is to invert the magneto meter `y` and `z` readings so that the *new*, virtual, axes of magnetometer and the axes of the accelerometer become the same.

Comment: 1) roll would be the rotation on the x axis, pitch on y axis and yaw on z axis

Comment: 3) It makes me think I'm using it wrong since I can't get consistent yaw angle data once I tilt the accelerometer and magnetometer.

when working without moving the xy plane the results of the yaw are consistent but once I tilt the xy plane a little the data varies when it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

1. AFAIK, the **sequence of the rotations** are also important. It is not given in the question. I will assume the sequence to go from inertial frame to body frame is (Yaw, Pitch, Roll) = (Z, Y, X). So the sequence to go from body to inertial is the reverse.
   Since these details are not present in the question, I assume the convention given in [Link 1](http://www.chrobotics.com/library/understanding-euler-angles) and [Link2](https://ae640a.github.io/assets/winter17/slides/Lecture%203.pdf#page=11).
2. Accelerometer frame is same as IMU reference

### The transformation

The measured vectors are obtained in IMU (accelerometer) frame. To take a vector resolved in IMU frame, to inertial(?) frame, the transformation as given in the above reference is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v
\end{bmatrix}^I_{3\times1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    C\psi & -S\psi & 0\\
    S\psi & C\psi & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\color{red}{
\begin{bmatrix}
    C\theta & 0 & S\theta\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    -S\theta & 0 & C\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & C\phi & -S\phi\\
    0 & S\phi & C\phi\\
\end{bmatrix}
}
\begin{bmatrix}
v
\end{bmatrix}^{IMU}_{3\times1}
$$

The red matrices indicate what I assume is the transformation equation set shown in the question.

Assume the magnetometer data was available in the same frame of reference as the accelerometer. Let that reading be \$[x_M', y_M'z_M']^T\$.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{M2}\\
y_{M2}\\
z_{M2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
C\theta & S\phi S\theta & C\phi S\theta\\
0 & C\phi & -S\phi\\
\dots & \dots & \dots
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{M}'\\
y_{M}'\\
z_{M}'
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since the Y and Z axes are inverted for the magnetometer, the above equation changes to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{M2}\\
y_{M2}\\
z_{M2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
C\theta & S\phi S\theta & C\phi S\theta\\
0 & C\phi & -S\phi\\
\dots & \dots & \dots
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{M}\\
\color{red}{-}y_{M}\\
\color{red}{-}z_{M}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The above is significantly different from your equations.

### Sanity check

You have mentioned in the comments that "*pitch on y axis*". This means that a rotation about pitch should leave the Y component of a vector unchanged (if it was the last operation performed). Equation for `yM` in the question doesn't seem to satisfy that logic. Of course, This check is only correct assuming a certain *sequence of rotations*.

### Note

I see that your equations seem *almost* correct if the sequence of rotations to go from inertial frame to body frame is (Yaw, Roll, Pitch). *The negation on Y and Z components before applying the equations are still required.* So, see if your output becomes correct if you insert

```C
yM = -yM;
zM = -zM;
```

just before the transformation.